# Run Ubuntu 13.04 / Linux mint 14 on Amazon EC2 with 'NX free edition for Linux' from NoMachine

Tags: linux, ubuntu, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, nomachine-nx

I have recently been trying to create a Linux workstation in the cloud which I can access from any of my personal machines/OS using NX. I found a few old [guides](http://activeintelligence.org/blog/archive/remote-graphical-linux-desktop-on-ec2/) which I was following. I used the Ubuntu 13.04 AMI - [ami-1e831d77](http://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/locator/ec2/) . However, since Ubuntu has now moved to Unity by default, I could not exactly follow these guides step by step. I managed to set up the NX server in the EC2 but then connection from NX client on my local machine to EC2 does not work (which I had expected). What changes would I have to make for this to work? Could anyone recommend me a guide of some kind.

Any help would be appreciated.

PS: I am new to deploying EC2 instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what i used on 12.04 to get unity working is in the client using the option for a new virtual desktop, and the custom session "gnome-session --session=ubuntu-2d"